# Calculating Average/Sum for Day of the week - Cognos 10.2

Tags: cognos-10

I am a newbie to cognos world!

I am working on a data where I have to calculate average sales for days of the week (i.e Only Monday's Average, Only Tuesday's Average ...)

Our Data source is Cognos 10.2

To achieve the above requirement I calculated "Day" by using below mentioned syntax and successful in getting the results 1,2....7)

```
_day_of_week ([Time Metrics].[Transaction Date],1)
```

Now, my next step would be to write a syntax to display 1=Monday, 2= Tuesday, 7 = Sunday)

I calculated "Day of the week" by using below mentioned syntax and successful in getting the results for 'Monday' I guess using the same syntax i can get results for Tuesday, Wednesday and so on....

```
If ([Day]='1') then ('Monday') else (' ')
```

My ultimate target is to calculate Average and Sum of only Monday's ,Only Tuesdays and so on....

Now i hit a road block

I am clueless on how to proceed further, and this is my first real foray into Cognos queries so the syntax is fairly new to me.

It would of great help if any one help me to write syntax to calculate average and sum of only Monday's, Tuesdays and so on...

Looking forward for the positive response!

Thanks,
Ganesh

Answer (score 0):

Total:

```
total([Measure] for [Day])
```

Average:

```
average([Measure] for [Day])
```

Replace [Measure] with your actual measure data item.

The 'for' clause in aggregate functions behaves like a GROUP BY in a SQL statement. It defines the rollup grain for the function.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The above mentioned syntax results are static/fixed. The total value remains the same. I have data with Fiscal Year; Fiscal Month; Fiscal week and Transaction date. Can i have results dynamic... i mean average of only Monday's(Day1's) for a Fiscal Week/Fiscal Month.

Comment: Yes. The syntax above works for any value. It will give you a total (or average) for all Mondays, all Tuesdays in the entire resultset. If you need to define a more specific grouping you can add data items to the 'for' clause. For instance if you wanted to total for each fiscal month you could do total([Measure] for [Fiscal Month],[Fiscal Year]). If you wanted a total for each day of the week within each fiscal month then you would do total([Measure] for [Day],[Fiscal Month],[Fiscal Year].